# Error with VS2015 Universal Windows XAML Designer

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I have currently updated my machine to windows 10 and installed Visual Studio 2015. When creating a new Universal Windows application, I cannot view the Designer for MainPage.xaml. Here is the current error:

```
System.Exception
Install failed. Please contact your software vendor. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF9)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: Did you enable the developer mode in windows settings?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. I have also tried to re-install VS2015 and Repair as well.

Comment: Can you install any app from the Store?

Comment: This will be on a work machine, but I can see if i can get a simple weather app to download. How will this help with my designer issue?

Comment: I am currently unable to install any apps from the store.

Comment: That is the problem, something's wrong with your OS. Try googling `0x80073CF9`.

Comment: I'm not getting that error in the Store though, the issue I am having with the Store is once I go to install, a window appears that says choose an account, but no accounts are listed.

Comment: Did you add any MS account?

Comment: no, I have not added any MS accounts

Comment: Then add one and try installing any app from the Store.

Comment: Tried that, same situation as before.